# xcode create uiviewcontrollers on fly

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a project: first view is uitableview, when you select row uinavigationcontroller pushes you to secondviewcontroller - there are some info and at the end there is a small uitableview: 4 rows of competitors. When you select competitor uinavigationcontroller must push you to another view and in that view ,at the end of it, there are another 4 competitors and again you can select one. So if you understood there can be thousands of views when you select competitor.

So the question is what is view hierarchy and how I can implement this?

Here is a link to scheme what it should be like:
http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg837/scaled.php?server=837&filename=scheme.png&res=medium

Thanks for answers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a subclass of `UIViewController` for your info with small tableView and on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in that small tableView you create another instance of your subclass and push it to `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Ok, for example i push uiviewcontroller subclass, it pushes me , but after that there are another 4 rows and when i select one of those what action must be taken? User can select 100 competitors in a row, so views must be created on the fly.

Comment: I already told you - create new instance of subclass, provide it with necessary data about next competitors and push it into navController.

Comment: I misunderstood.. :( Ok, for example:
In didSelectRowAtIndexPath I create instance:
 SomeClass *class1 = [[SomeClass alloc]init];
[self.navigationcontroller pushViewController:class1 animated:YES];
It pushes me to class1. Now user in class1 and selects another 1 competitor. So what is next action?

Comment: Next is you repeat that. `SomeClass *class = [[SomeClass alloc]init]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:class animated:YES];`